# as3 fl.transitions.Tween could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to do some work with some custom tweening and I understand how I'm suppose to do it. However CS5 is not able to resolve my import statements.

I have

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
```

and both of these cause an error. The error is "definition fl.transitions.Tween or easing could not be found"

The import statements are turning blue so flash is recognizing the path and I am able to import other fl components like fl.controls and fl.events. Why is my program unable to resolve these imports and how can I fix it? Please be explicit and detailed with any answers you give.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: stop using the flash.transitions :) get something more powerful and usefull: http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/ also check there are much more than tweening.

Comment: The company I work for has not approved any external classes so I cannot use them. Trust me I know about them and wish I could but it's out of the question.

Comment: Is your fla file set to AS2? then change it to AS3.

Comment: or if you need to use AS2, then `import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;`

Comment: Please check whether the as3 class path is right or not  in preference?

Comment: my link is C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\projects\Flash\src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update: as @William pointed out, the package is from 2008, use at your own risk ;)**

you can grab the FL package as an *.swc from our blog:

http://apdevblog.com/update-using-flvideo-package-w-eclipse-and-fdt3/

and than just add the swc to your source path in the flash ide.

Comment: Found the source path and was able to add a new source path to the file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Beware! That library package is from 2008. It will cause a lot of stuff to break in 2014.

Comment: @William these are the dangers of still doing actionscript in 2014 ;) better beware

Comment: @William just kidding, do you have a more current link to share?

Comment: Not sure where you can find a more updated package online. You can still find the relevant SWC in the default classpath if you have Flash Professional installed. Can't recall the path off the top of my head, but there is a lot of info you can find in other forums posts out there.