# Getting to know Flash IDEs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to learn AS3 by downloading Flash Projects(open source), but can't seem to really grasp the right way to get the projects to run (through compiling) with IDEs (I am using FlashDevelop as an IDE). Here's an example:

http://www.flashkit.com/movies/Games/Shooting-manish_c-12372/index.php

Here's what I try to do:

1. I open a new Project on FlashDevelop
2. I copy all the folders to src, and make the main file(In this project it's called "rhymingRockets.as") as the Document Class.
3. I delete main.as (generated by default), and try to run it, but get the errors: Error: Definition fl.transitions.easing could not be found.

[Click here to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrxF.jpg)

Sorry for bothering you with such a simple question, but any help will be greatly appreciated, as I am new to Flash.

Comment: anything in the `fl` name space is specific to FlashProfessional.

Comment: Ok, so there isnt a way to compile projects with fl namespace with any IDEs other than flashpro? (For example flashdevelop)

Comment: There is, you can export a swc from flash pro with the appropriate libraries, or, find the source class files for them all in the Flash Pro Configuration -> Component Source  folder.

Comment: If you don't have FlashPro, there lots of places to find it on the web:  Here's one: https://code.google.com/p/pmprivatelibrary/source/browse/trunk/fl/?r=10  - just keep in mind, if you want to use any of the visual components, you'll need the ComponentShim graphical assets as well as the class files.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Definition fl.transitions.easing

That error indicates that you are not linking to the [fl.transitions.easing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/easing/package-detail.html) library/package correctly. There is a related question here ([as3 fl.transitions.Tween could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679365/as3-fl-transitions-tween-could-not-be-found)). If someone is sharing the source of a project, they may not have shared the source code or compiled .swc for any libraries the project may use since that is not project specific.

You might find this link of use: [Linking .swc files in your ActionScript Editor](http://cote.cc/blog/linking-swc-files-in-your-actionscript-editor). Since you say you are new to Actionscript, I'd suggest that you don't waste too much time on getting 3rd party projects to run – I realize it's tempting but not much learning from that and lots of frustration. Better to work with your own small learning projects to try out different ideas or libraries.

Comment: The Developer of that project did leave behind a .swf file and now I tried linking it by going to properties - Output file and selecting it, but still it doesn't work. I also tried linking that old .swf that i found in one of your links and it did not work. I just need to run it through some IDE in order to edit it later on.

Comment: I didn't notice the difference,  my bad.  He did not leave behind a .swc file, and for some reason the rest of the open source projects I've downloaded don't include it. So every time I download an old project I need to find a fitting swc file? (Btw I really have no interest on that project or any of the rest I have downloaded,  I just need to compile every time I make a change in order to learn. )